# NCL Path setting Ubuntu

Tags: paths, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having a problem trying to convert a file using the ncl_convert2nc command. Every time I do, I get this message:

```
fatal:NclGRIB2: Invalid Product Definition Template.
fatal:Could not open (./01ZAPR222011.grb2)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So I tried this code to a different NCL:

```
export $NCARG_ROOT=/home/jp2nyy/NCL6.3:$PATH
```

but it gives me this message:

```
bash: export:`/home/jp2nyy/NCL6.3:/home/jp2nyy/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games=/home/jp2nyy/NCL6.3:/home/jp2nyy/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games': not a valid identifier
```

I have tried to look at other posts on the NCL but it was not helpful.

Comment: I don't know anything about `ncl_convert2nc`, but it looks like the error is that the input file cannot be opened - are you sure the directory where you are running the command contains the file? FYI your `export` command is malformed (remove the `$` from `$NCARG_ROOT`) - though I doubt it will help

Comment: I am sure that it is in the directory. And removing the $ does not help it.